# Нахождение количества элементов вектора, равных среднему арифметическому элементов этого вектора

Tags: c++

Необходимо найти количество элементов вектора, равных среднему арифметическому элементу вектора.

Ниже привел код по нахождению среднего арифметического. А как посчитать кол-во элементов, равных этому среднему арифметическому — не знаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> temp;
    temp.push_back(10);
    temp.push_back(15);
    temp.push_back(20);
    temp.push_back(10);
    temp.push_back(15);
    temp.push_back(25);
    temp.push_back(15);

    int avg_temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        avg_temp += temp[i];
    }

    avg_temp /= 7;
    cout << avg_temp << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Но этот код не находит среднее арифметическое. Он выполняет целочисленное деление, т.е. деление с округлением вниз. Такое среднее арифметическое является неточным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> temp;
    temp.push_back(10);
    temp.push_back(15);
    temp.push_back(20);
    temp.push_back(10);
    temp.push_back(15);
    temp.push_back(25);
    temp.push_back(15);

    int avg_temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        avg_temp += temp[i];
    }
    avg_temp /= 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {

        if (avg_temp == temp[i])
            count++;
    }
    cout << avg_temp << endl;
    cout << "======" << endl;
    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ` вывод печатью ` не очень понял

Answer (score 5):

Если по-максимуму использовать стандартную библиотеку, то можно так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {10,15,20,10,15,25,15};

    int mean = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0) / v.size();
    int count = std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), mean);

    std::cout << "Среднее: " << mean << '\n'
              << "Встречается раз: " << count << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

В комментариях верно заметили, что в таком случае дробная часть среднего арифметического отбрасывается. (Код в вопросе делает то же самое, так что решил не трогать.)

Если хочется этого избежать, делаем так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {10,15,20,10,15,25,15};

    int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    float mean = sum / float(v.size());

    int count = sum % int(v.size()) ? 0 : std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), sum / int(v.size()));

    std::cout << "Среднее: " << mean << '\n'
              << "Встречается раз: " << count << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что это самый сжатый вариант?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну ладно, может неудачно выразился.

Comment: Да, неудачно, но подход к решению нужен именно такой

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а по-моему, вы удачно высказались, ведь из всех представленных ответов, ваш — действительно самый сжатый.

Comment: @eanmos,  из всех представленных ответов, но не самый сжатый. Тем более, что любая кричилька о том, что мой является самым самым, является неудачным высказыванием. Чтобы это понять, нужно просто иметь  понятие о культуре общения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, какая еще «кричилька»? HolyBlackCat и не говорил, что его ответ «самый-самый». Ответ, кстати, действительно *самый сжатый*. Нужно выполнить два действия: а) найти сред. арифметическое; б) найти кол-во элементов, равных сред. арифметическому. Два действия — две функции. Думаете, можно написать короче? Конечно, можно убрать присваивания и делать `cout << accumulate(...)`, но толку от этого?

Comment: тогда  я напишу другой

Comment: @eanmos,  он вначале именно так и говорил. Он понел свою ошибку, а вы нет. Но всеравно он ошибся второй раз, говоря о максимальном использовании STL,  Просто нужго отвечать и спрашивать для своего общего блага , при это оставаясь адекватным

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, о каких ошибках вы постоянно говорите?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, ну там же отбрасывается дробная часть. Посмотрите комментарий AnT-а под вопросом, он уже написал об этом.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Согласен, добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то типо такого. Созаете переменную `count`, и в цикле считаете `if ( temp[i] == avg_temp) ++count;`

Comment: можно еще std::count_if - но думаю в данном случае это будут премудрости.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще такой вариант, для тех, кто говорит о максимальной сжатости или максимальном использовании библиотеки( ни один ответ не может являеться самым самым)

```
std::valarray<int> v{10,15,20,10,15,25,15};
cout <<"ответ: " << std::count(&v[0], &v[v.size()], v.sum()/v.size());
```

Тут всего одна строчка

Comment: А где вывод среднего арифметического?

Comment: Интересно. В голову не пришло взять valarray. Но вместо `&v[v.size()]` лучше взять `&v[0]+v.size()`, а то если собрать с флажком на проверку границ контейнеров, то на этом месте вылетит assertion: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2d9d0a693387ee7

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я с вами категорически не соглашусь  &v[v.size()] не может являться ошибкой, и вместо него использовать другую запись вы можете, но нельзя говорить  что одна запись лучше другого, так как они идентичны, только предлогаемая вами запись  включает в себя больше символов  и  менее читабельна , если по мне...

Comment: Тем более. автору нужно найти кол-во элементов *вектора*.

Comment: `&v[v.size()]` — вылет за границы, нет?

Comment: @eanmos, v.sum()/v.size() это среднее арифметическое, а   альгоритм возвращает именно  то, что нужно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, у HolyBlackCat в ответе есть вывод среднего арифметического на stdout. В вашем ответе этого нет. Так что вы не можете говорить, что ваш ответ более сжатый, просто потому что ваш ответ делает не то, что ответ HolyBlackCat. Минус мой.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, причем тут  утверждения? Вы просто не до конца понели смысль использования итератора (указателья) , содержащего адресс элемента за конец последовательности, который используется в стандартных альгоритмах

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan,  использовать значение нельзя, но  написать  while ( (int*) p != &v[v.size()] )  вполне логично, что и делается в стандартных альгоритмах. И закроем эту тему. Если кому не до конца понятно что то, оформляйте вопрос

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Можете показать, где именно так делается?

Comment: А то я вот открыл стандарт, читаю про [`valarray::operator[]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/numarray#valarray.access), и там прямым текстом написано *"Requires: n < size()."*. Я так понимаю, иначе - неопределенно поведение. Я же показал по ссылке выше, что со специальном флажком ГЦЦ останавливает программу на этом месте, выдавая ошибку. А вот `&v[0]+v.size()` уже не является неопределенным поведением, потому что разрешено вот [здесь](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4).

Comment: Значение &v[v.size] точно нельзя использовать, но кроме этого просто вызывать оператор "квадратные скобки" с таким значением тоже некорректно: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/operator[]/  N: ***Values equal or greater than the object's size cause undefined behavior.***

Comment: Кстати, если даже где-то в исходниках стандартных алгоритмов, в реализации какого-то компилятора и есть такое, не стоит на это смотреть, авторы знают свой компилятор и как он ведет себя в этом случае. Т.е. на другом компиляторе (или даже на том же самом в следующей версии) может и не работать.